# Unable to call one python file using pywinauto into another file using ironpython

Tags: python, ironpython, pywinauto

I'm performing desktop application automation using pywinauto. And need to perform certain actions which requires interacting with `c#` files so using `ironpython`. Now I need to perform the two actions together so calling one file into another.

`ironpython` gives the following error:

> `ImportError: No module named pywinauto.application`.

Comment: How did you install pywinauto to ironpython? It’s different Python interpreter which doesn’t use CPython installation at all. Also I suspect pyWin32 can’t be easily installed on ironpython because it shall be compiled against it.

Comment: Why not using CPython packages that can deal with .NET assemblies? Like pythonnet: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

Comment: I had to use two different interpreter earlier to run pywinauto and ironpython. That was the problem I was facing. But, yes using pythonnet I don't have to do that. I can have pywinauto and c# modules run together using one interpreter.